# Datatable using primefaces doesnt filter

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

My datatable show results, but doesnt filter by protocolo, using JSF works, but promefaces nothing show anything, my code is:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{registroBean.listarRegistros()}"
                         var="registro"
                          widgetVar="registroTable"
                         id="tabelaRegistro"
                         class="table table-striped table-hover"
                         rendered="#{not empty registroBean.listarRegistros()}">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('registroTable').filter()" style="width:100%" placeholder="Digite o protocolo" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </f:facet>

                <p:column filterBy="{#registro.protocolo}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Protocolo</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{registro.protocolo}" />
                </p:column>

 </p:dataTable>
```

When I enter a search return:
No records found.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1:_"what am I doing wrong?"_ Not creating a [mcve]. see also http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ but maybe you are lucky. `filterBy="{#registro.protocolo}"` is wrong. The # should be outside the {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an empty ArrayList for filtered results in your Managed Bean and set it to your DataTable like this :

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{registroBean.listarRegistros()}"
                     filteredValue="#{registroBean.filtredRegistro}"
                     var="registro"
                     widgetVar="registroTable"
                     id="tabelaRegistro"
                     class="table table-striped table-hover"
                     rendered="#{not emptyregistroBean.listarRegistros()}">
```

and add this attribut with getter and setter in you RegistroBean

```
private ArrayList<YourClass> filtredRegistro;

//Getter And Setter
public ArrayList<YourClass> getfiltredRegistro(){
   return this.filtredRegistro;
}
public void setfiltredRegistro(filtredRegistro){
       this.filtredRegistro=filtredRegistro;
    }
```

Comment: Effectively doing what is done in the PrimeFaces showcase? ;-)

Comment: Yes Sir :D ! Novice contribution. Together we can do more :D